# how to call subprocess.check_call with a quoted argument on windows?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
subprocess.check_call(["C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash", "-c", '"echo hello; echo goodbye"'], shell=True)
```

on windows, returns:

```
/usr/bin/bash: echo hello; echo goodbye: command not found
```

however, running:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "echo hello; echo goodbye"
```

gives the expected output:

```
hello
goodbye
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: have you tried  to separate the commands `subprocess.check_call(["C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash", "-c", "echo","hello","\ngoodbye"])`

Comment: calling bash through the shell seems superfluous

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's a good suggestion but I want to call two very separate commands, I just used `"echo hello; echo goodbye"` for illustration.

Comment: @wim have you got any other ideas how to do it? basically I've got a script from another team that I need to get working. however I do that doesn't matter too much to me. :)

Comment: the quotes inside quotes would cause an error

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're right. That's what I'm trying to solve. :)

Comment: Sorry yes, just saw the title,  why are there " inside '?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm trying to replicate the same effect as running `C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "echo hello; echo goodbye"` in a shell.

Comment: does it not work using just `"echo hello; echo goodbye"`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ahh, sorry i should have mentioned that case and thus my motivation for this question. That just returns hello and doesnt run the second part.

Comment: @eryksun it seems that calling `subprocess.check_call('C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash -c "echo hello; echo goodbye"')` works. do you want to put this as an answer? (and maybe elaborate a little more, I didn't fully understand your explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows process has to parse its own argument list from the command line that gets passed to [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In contrast, POSIX systems use the [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) and [`spawn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) functions, which take an already parsed `argv` array.

On Windows, `subprocess.Popen` calls `subprocess.list2cmdline` to convert a list to a command-line string. This assumes [VC++ parsing rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so a literal quote character will be escaped as `\"`. If Cygwin uses different rules from VC++, just pass `args` as a string instead of a list. For example:

```
subprocess.check_call(r'C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "echo hello; echo goodbye"')
```

You can also explicitly provide the executable.

```
subprocess.check_call('bash -c "echo hello; echo goodbye"', 
                      executable=r'C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe')
```

It gets passed to `CreateProcess` as the `lpApplicationName` parameter.